# php script not executed by crontab

Tags: permissions, scripts, php, cron

I have setup a cron to execute one of my php scripts. But the problem is the php script is not being executed at all not even partially.

Here is the cron I have set up

```
45 23 * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/myscript.php
```

I have tried the following

1. I removed the cron from normal user to root user still no results.
2. I changed the permissions on the script using `chmod +x /var/www/myscript.php`
3. I have used the command `whereis php` it gives the following

   ```
   php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
   ```

Now, I don't know what else I can do. Please Help.

P.S. I can execute the script manully and it runs perfectly.

Comment: Errors from scripts run by crontab should show up in your system logs or you should receive them as a local email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. As `man php` tells us...

```
   --no-header
   -q             Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).

   --file file
   -f file        Parse and execute file
```

`-q` doesn't do *anything* in php-cli mode. As others have pointed out, you need `-f`.

#### 2. +x is not required.

Revert it with:

```
chmod -x /var/www/myscript.php
```

#### 3. `whereis` will give you all locations. If you just want the binary, use `which php`.

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just taking a wild guess but shouldn't the path where you place the script be

> 45 23 * * * /usr/bin/php   /var/www/html/myscript.php

i am still a newbie at cron :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct crontab line would be:

```
45 23 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/myscript.php
```

Notice the `-f` instead of `-q`!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please let me know the difference between both. I mean -f and -q

Answer (score 0):

See `man cron` and the Debian-specific changes. Quote:

>
As described above, the files under these directories have to  be  pass
       some  sanity checks including the following: be executable, be owned by
       root, not be writable by group or other  and,  if  symlinks,  point  to
       files  owned  by root. Additionally, the file names must conform to the
       filename requirements of run-parts: they must be entirely  made  up  of
       letters,  digits  and  can  only  contain the special signs underscores
       ('_') and hyphens ('-'). Any  file  that  does  not  conform  to  these
       requirements  will not be executed by run-parts.  For example, any file
       containing dots will be ignored.